# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient XmlException on SqlConnection.Open - "Root element is missing"

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient, microsoft-data-sqlclient

We have upgraded an application to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` from `System.Data.SqlClient` because we need Always Encrypted support. However, upon upgrading it is throwing an exception open attempting to create a new `SqlConnection`. I've tried various permutations of connection string flavor but nothing has helped.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Connect Timeout=60; uid=admin;pwd=password") //Throws XmlException - "Root element is missing"
{
    conn.Open(); 
}
```

Stack trace (not very helpful)

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
    System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
    System.Configuration.XmlUtil.XmlUtil(System.IO.Stream, string, bool, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
    System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, and you'd want to file an issue for that.

Comment: What's the stack trace?  Have you perhaps got a corrupt config file?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added the (useless) stack trace it's giving me. I initially said it was on Open but it actually seems to actually be in the constructor. I put the cnn string in there directly to rule out any config file issue.

Comment: Yep.  You've got a corrupted configuration file. Either YourApp.exe.config, web.config, or the Machine.Config.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Why is it looking in any file when I manually pass a connection string to its constructor? System.Data.SqlClient was working perfectly prior to the upgrade.

Comment: They should both need to read your app config file and the machine config file, and a quick test with procmon shows that they both do.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Deleting the app.config file worked, thanks. Though this is definitely a regression from System.Data.SqlClient because we made no code changes and this started happening. That said, I failed when trying to make a simple repro project so I'm not sure how to report this on Github.